# Right Function to Return an Unknown Number of Characters for a sting

Tags: ms-access, vba

If my Access database I use a string of information to save files to a particular location. At the end of the string there is always an associated File Extension for each one. I need to be able to pull this information from the string to store it a table field.

String Example:

```
\\Server\MainFolder\Location\2\LastFolder\02-1234-LastName-20150119_080718FileExtension
```

I would like to use the Right function to pull back that "FileExtension" piece which could be an infinite number of letters, characters and numbers.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to extract... is it everything after the `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` bit? And your `FileExtension` is just a placeholder for illustration purposes? Have you considered trying something?

Comment: Can you define what "that "FileExtension" piece" is?

Comment: Because you did not put a period in front of `FileExtension`, would it be correct to assume you put the file extension as part of the string? `02-1234-LastName-20150119_080718FileExtension.FileExtension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for

```
yourPath = "\Server\MainFolder\Location\2\LastFolder\02-1234-LastName-20150119_080718.FileExtension"
whatYouNeed = Mid(yourPath, InStrRev(yourPath, ".") + 1)
```

, if FileExtension is preceded by a `.` period.

Comment: You mean a period? (.)

Answer (score 2):

The answers given here already may work in limited situations, but are certainly not the best way to go about it. Don't reinvent the wheel. The [File System Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx) in the [Microsoft Scripting Runtime library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bstcxhf7(v=vs.84).aspx) already has a method to do exactly this. It's called [GetExtensionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0fxha2a(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
Function GetAnExtension(fullFilePath As String) As String
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   GetAnExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fullFilePath)
End Function
```

Comment: I think his extension is part of the string itself... Ex. `/blahxls.xls`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `InStrRev()` and `Mid()`

`InStrRev()` lets you search for a sub-string within a string but **In** **Rev**erse and returns it's starting position. We can combine this with the `Mid()` function to tell VBA where we want to start grabbing text from:

```
Sub SO()

x$ = "\Server\MainFolder\Location\2\LastFolder\02-1234-LastName-20150119_080718FileExtension"

fileExt$ = Mid(x, InStrRev(x, "\") + 1) 'fileExt now holds information you need

End Sub
```

will grab everything after the final "\" which is what your initial question implied you were after.